# Why default build tasks in vs code runs in powershell instead of the default terminal selected?

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal, git-bash

I am trying to configure vs code for live input/output for c++ codes using input.txt and output.txt files through build tasks.
I took a reference from https://github.com/jspw/VS-Code-Config/blob/master/windows.md
After pressing ctrl+shift+b it should automatically take the input from input.txt and show the output in output.txt.
Earlier it worked, but after updating vs code to 1.60.0 it shows an error like this:
[Error thrown when pressing ctrl + shift + b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cudOf.png)

It seems instead of running in git-bash, build tasks executes in powershell. Also my default terminal is selected as git-bash, still it runs in powershell. How to correct this?

This is my tasks.json
[Code inside tasks.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX1BB.png)

Comment: It's a known bug in v1.60.0, expected to be fixed in v1.60.1, soon.

Comment: I rolled back to vs code 1.59.0 and now it works. Thanks for your precious time and attention.